# Merge tags on superuser [virtualmachine], [virtual-machine], and [virtualization]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I noticed a similar question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7929/change-virtualmachine-and-virtualdesktop-to-virtual-machine-and-virtual-desktop), but it seems nothing has been done...  On superuser there are tags for virtualmachine and virtual-machine.  I think these two at the least should be merged, if not also merge virtualization with it.  I mean first of all, virtualization is not a word haha... and second, it doesn't make sense to have two or three tags for the same thing.  Redundant and inefficient.  Please merge them.

Comment: Add `vm` to the mix, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following merges. I used the latter since it is the most commonly used.

<kbd>virtual-machine</kbd> --> <kbd>vitualmachine</kbd>
<kbd>vm</kbd> --> <kbd>virtualmachine</kbd>

However I am not merging <kbd>virtualization</kbd> since it has a different meaning to <kbd>virtualmachine</kbd>.

Comment: Normally names in tags are separated by hyphen on SOFU, aren't they? So [virtual-machine] would be correct.

Comment: @John Normally yes. However in this case I went with the tag most used since this is the tag the community is using and this is what was used during the previous re-tag.